# Can only connect to Google services

Tags: networking, dns, google

I am quite new to Ubuntu and Linux in general and have been experiencing the following issue for the last week or so:

I am only able to connect to websites from Google when using a wireless connection; a wired one works perfectly fine.

I just did a reinstall and it worked fine on a fresh Ubuntu for around 5 minutes until it stopped working again.

This occurred to me on Debian, Kubuntu and now 'stock' Ubuntu with Gnome as well.

I've been searching for a solution for this but haven't been able to find anything useful.
What I already tried:

- Deleting the connection and re-adding it,
- Reinstalling my OS: From Debian to KDE Neon (Kubuntu) to Ubuntu
  (current),
- Deleting the connection in the router (not sure if it would help
  anyway but who knows),
- Factory Reset on the Router

All other devices work fine. Since I can connect to Google a hardware problem isn't likely. I've heard something about incorrectly setup DNS servers or something, maybe something isn't configured as it should be?

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! Please [edit] your question and tell us your problem.  Which browser do you use? What does work and what doesn't? ("I am only able to connect to websites from Google when using a wireless connection; a wired one works perfectly fine" sounds like everything is alright?)

Comment: I'm sorry, maybe I got you wrong: is your problem that you can _only access google websites_ using the wireless connection? If so, is your _wireless connection_ tethered?

Comment: When using the wireless connection I can only access google websites using the default firefox. However, pinging them from the terminal doesn't work and it tells me that the hostname is unresolvable which is very odd. Thunderbird and Filezilla don't work as well.
A wired connection to the router works perfectly fine.

The connection is not tethered, I am connected directly to my router through wifi and I can access it's configuration interface. I am using a new Lenovo V110-15IKB 80TH001UGE if that helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally managed to fix it. Setting the DNS manually in the IPv4 settings seems to work. Maybe its a problem with my ISP's DNS servers but changing it to use OpenDNS (208.67.220.220) worked for me.